# github project is not working on xampp

Tags: php, github, xampp

My github project is imported to `c:/xampp/htdocs/project` but it is producing an error for the autoload file. It is not able to find `system.php` file which is in `c:/xampp/php/pear/system.php`. When I move `system.php` file to `htdocs` directory, I receive a class not found error. The error is in autoload file.

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/system.php'); //System Settings
require_once('global.php'); //Global methods and variables

//Auto loading of classes
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . 'Class.php');
});
```

Comment: what's the framework of this project?

Comment: maybe this project need to composer.

Comment: what is mean by that jay?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem today. It looks there is a problem using the filename "system.php". Renaming it to something else solved my problem.